# How do I fix this "address family not supported by protocol" error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.0 with JDK 6. My build target is Android 2.2. I'm developing under Windows 7.

I'm trying to fetch an XML file like the following:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
try {
    //get a new instance of parser
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

    //parse the file and also register this class for call backs
    sp.parse("http://ipaddress/my/valid/path.xml", this);
}catch(SAXException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I'm getting a permission denied error (caused by socket exception) in the debugger. 
Apart from that, I also get `sntpclient error: address family not supported by protocol.`
Here are the detailed logs:

```
09-29 16:13:40.181: WARN/System.err(304): java.io.IOException: Couldn't open http://213.137.198.141:8085/MarketDataServiceV3.asmx/GetIntraday?instrument=FSPAA.ST&from=2010-09-01&to=2010-09-20&authentication=D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E&nocache=true
09-29 16:13:40.200: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.openUrl(ExpatParser.java:759)
09-29 16:13:40.210: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:291)
09-29 16:13:40.210: WARN/System.err(304):     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
09-29 16:13:40.220: WARN/System.err(304):     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:268)
09-29 16:13:40.230: WARN/System.err(304):     at aiCharts.GettingStarted.MySAXParser.parseDocument(MySAXParser.java:45)
09-29 16:13:40.239: WARN/System.err(304):     at aiCharts.GettingStarted.DataFactory.getChartDataByWebService(DataFactory.java:30)
09-29 16:13:40.249: WARN/System.err(304):     at aiCharts.GettingStarted.GettingStartedActivity.onCreate(GettingStartedActivity.java:42)
09-29 16:13:40.249: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-29 16:13:40.260: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-29 16:13:40.270: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-29 16:13:40.279: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-29 16:13:40.279: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-29 16:13:40.289: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 16:13:40.289: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 16:13:40.301: WARN/System.err(304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-29 16:13:40.301: WARN/System.err(304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 16:13:40.320: WARN/System.err(304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-29 16:13:40.320: WARN/System.err(304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-29 16:13:40.331: WARN/System.err(304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-29 16:13:40.339: WARN/System.err(304):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 16:13:40.351: WARN/System.err(304): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
09-29 16:13:40.370: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
09-29 16:13:40.390: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
09-29 16:13:40.390: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
09-29 16:13:40.399: WARN/System.err(304):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
09-29 16:13:40.409: WARN/System.err(304):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
09-29 16:13:40.409: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
09-29 16:13:40.419: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
09-29 16:13:40.431: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
09-29 16:13:40.441: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
09-29 16:13:40.441: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1152)
09-29 16:13:40.450: WARN/System.err(304):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.openUrl(ExpatParser.java:757)
09-29 16:13:40.450: WARN/System.err(304):     ... 19 more
09-29 16:14:26.580: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol`
```

I can parse the file when I run it separately as a Java application. I have also permitted internet access in the manifest. The manifest entry is:

```
uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"
```

Comment: Can you provide the `root cause` of the socket exception?

Comment: That "Address family not supported by protocol" message comes from SntpClient and higly likely is completely unrelated to the problem you are having.